# Changing password using Jabber Net

Tags: .net, xmpp

I was wondering whether it is is possible to modify a user's password using Jabber Net. If so, is there a neat way to verify first that the old password is indeed valid before modifying it to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log in first.  This will ensure that the old password is correct.  Then, use the Register commands.  See the example ([MainForm.cs](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/Example/MainForm.cs)) for the similar code, but the important bits are:

```
jc.OnRegisterInfo += new jabber.client.RegisterInfoHandler(jc_OnRegisterInfo);
jc.OnRegistered += new jabber.client.IQHandler(jc_OnRegistered);

jc.Password = "New Password";
jc.Register(new JID(jc.User, jc.Server, null));

// Called back when server sends registration form
private bool jc_OnRegisterInfo(object sender, Register r)
{
    if (r.Form == null)
        return true;

    // Some newer servers may use XData for registration
    muzzle.XDataForm f = new muzzle.XDataForm(r.Form);
    if (f.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return false;
    f.FillInResponse(r.Form);
    return true;
}

// Done setting password
private void jc_OnRegistered(object sender, IQ iq)
{
}
```